# How to build a relationship between two tables on ERD by dependency on specific attribute

Tags: database, relationship, data-analysis, diagram, erd

I am building ERD (Entity-Relationship Diagram) for data analysis report.
I have two tables
first: Account (it could be for clients and employee)
second: Promo codes (it should be generating by employee only)

Account attributes: Name, Phone_number, Email_add, Country, City, account_ID, account_type (which could be 1-client 2-employee)

Promo codes attributes: promo_code_ID, account_ID, promo_code_expired_date, promo_code_value

if the account type is employee then he can Generate the promo codes
if it isn't an employee then there is no relationship

how can i draw this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every `Account` is either `Client` or `Employee` (disjoint), then the following ERD seems possible:

[image: ERD]

The above diagram basically shows `Client` and `Employee` as subclasses of the `Account` entity. That is, each one inherits all attributes of `Account`.

Entities are contained in rectangles, attributes in ellipses, and the relation is contained by a rhombus. Underlined attributes denote primary keys.

The letter `d` (next to `Account`) denotes **disjoint** subclassing. That is, an `Account` cannot be both an `Employee` and a `Client`. The double line between `d` and `Account` denotes that **every** `Account` is either one of the subclasses.

One way to convert the above diagram to a relation data model, is exactly by creating only one table for all the `Account`s, along with using a *type* flag in that table, as in your case.

As you can see in the above diagram, only an `Employee` may issue `PromoCode`s (and not a `Client`).